# Form validation in Vue.js using computed property

Tags: forms, vue.js, validation

I have a form that I need to validate. This is just one field that I have specified. I'm trying to validate it using computed property.

```
<input 
   type="text"
   v-model="buyerName"
   placeholder="Name"
   autocomplete="on"
   required
>
<span class="errorNotification" >{{validateName}}</span>
```

This is the computed property 'validateName' I'm using

```
computed: {
  validateName(){
    return (this.buyerName !== "" ? "" : "Enter your name"); 
  }
}
```

[image]

This is how I am getting when the page is loaded. Is there a way to display the error message only when that field is in focus?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with v-if directive, set default value for the buyerName as null;

Your input field:

```
<input type="text"
       name="name"
       id="name"
       v-model="buyerName()"
       required>
 <span v-if="errors" class="errorNotification">{{ errors }}</span>
```

You js code:

```
data:{
  errors:null,
  buyerName:null
},
methods:{
  checkForm:function(e) {
    this.errors = null;
    if (this.buyerName!=null && this.buyerName!="") {
      //your actions if form is valid
      console.log("success");
    } else {
      this.errors = "Name required.";
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

}

Check examples of validation in doc: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/form-validation.html